# pandasの読み込みでエラー

Tags: python, pandas

csvファイルを読み込むためにpandasを使いたいのですが、エラーが発生します。

ソースコード(エラーと関係なさそうな部分は省略しています)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
import os
import csv
import pandas as pd

def main():

    width = 320
    height = 240
    num = int(0)
    os.chdir("d:\\study_data\\get_image\\temperature")

    while True:

        filename = 'temperature_'+format(num)+'.csv'
        #1,2行目は無視して読み込み
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            csv = pd.read_csv(filename,skiprows=2,header=None)
        #全部のcsvファイルを変換できたら終了
        else:
            print("End")
            break

        #1番右の余分な列を排除
        csv = csv.dropna(axis=1)

        #リスト(1次元配列)に格納
        csv = csv.values.tolist()
        csv = np.array(csv)
        #2次元配列に変換
        csv = csv.reshape(height,width)

        num += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

出力内容

```
C:\Users\saino>python D:\study_data\get_image\T2I.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\saino\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib
  File "C:\Users\saino\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pandas._libs.interval import Interval
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\study_data\get_image\T2I.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\saino\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

```
ImportError: C extension: No module named 'pandas._libs.interval' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

とあったので、コマンドプロンプト上で`python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force`を実行すれば解決すると思うのですが、Cドライブ内で setup.py で検索するとたくさん出てきてどのsetup.pyを実行すればいいのか分からず足止めを食らっています。

<実行環境>

Windows10
python 3.8 (Anaconda)

<行ったこと>
pandasのインストールのし直しは行いました。

```
conda uninstall pandas
conda install pandas
```

Comment: [TouchDesignerでPython外部ライブラリのError](http://blog.livedoor.jp/madoka55537-vjtry/archives/25458972.html)という記事で同一のエラー対応として環境変数のパスを追加していました。ご参考までに。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。環境変数のパスが追加されていないということですがどこのパスを追加すればいいでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

無事実行できました。

環境変数のパスが通っていない可能性があるとのご指摘をいただき、
実際にそれが原因だったのかは分かりませんが以下に自分のやったことを記載しておきます。

```
conda create -n 仮想環境名 python=3.6
call activate.bat 仮想環境名
conda install pandas -y
```

アナコンダプロンプトでpythonのバージョンを3.6にした仮想環境を作成し、
そのうえで実行したらできました。
python3.8.5だと対応してなかったのでしょうか。